# Is CultureInfo.LCID available to Xamarin portable class libraries?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm looking to use the **`LCID`** and **`GetCultureInfo(int)`** members of `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` in a portable class library that targets Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, and .NET Framework 4.5.

The [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.LCID/) suggests that these members should be available.

However, the usages generate compiler errors CS1061 and CS0117 respectively:

```
CS1061: 'CultureInfo' does not contain a definition for 'LCID' [snip]
CS0117: 'CultureInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetCultureInfo'
```

How can I access these two members?

Comment: If you are using a profile that includes Windows Phone, LCID is not included.

Comment: @Jason good thought, but nah, I'm just targeting Xamarin and WPF

Comment: which profile, specifically?

Comment: @Jason I believe it's 78 – the one you get with both Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: @Jason actually, there's an issue. Seems that Windows Phone Silverlight 8 has somehow come along for the ride. :/

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can get away from that.  You can use DI to get that behavior from the platform projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason points out, these items are not available in a PCL. Typically the easiest way to see if it's supported would be the following doc:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.100).aspx

or manually looking at the pcl profile assemblies:

https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1658231-how-can-i-view-what-libraries-are-supported-in-a-pcl-

(In this case you can decompile the System.Globalization.dll and view the CultureInfo class)

However you can use `LCID` and `GetCultureInfo(int)` via the `mscorlib` that is provided in Xamarin.iOS / Xamarin.Android (monotouch.dll and Mono.Android.dll). You can use DI to accomplish this from a PCL.